# How to Reimplement ObservableCollection.this[index]

Tags: c#, observablecollection

The following does not work as expected: `"derived called"` is not printed. I am new to C# and probably I am missing some rule.

Thank you.

```
class Test<T> : ObservableCollection<T>, IList<T>, IList
{
  T IList<T>.this[int index]
  {
    get { Console.WriteLine("derived called"); return default(T); }
    set => throw new NotSupportedException();
  }

  object IList.this[int index]
  {
    get { Console.WriteLine("derived called"); return default(T); }
    set => throw new NotSupportedException();
  }
}
// ...
var t = new Test<int>() { 1 };
int i = t[0];

var oc = (ObservableCollection<int>)t;
int j = oc[0];
```

Comment: You've replaced the `IList<T>` implementation but you're accessing it through `ObservableCollection<T>` and you haven't overridden that member.

Comment: @madreflection Could you please elaborate? I do not understand.

Comment: There are two things to point out here. First, as Joe H's answer alludes, `this[int]` isn't virtual, so it can't be overridden. Shadowing (`new`) is the best you'll get. What you're trying to do isn't possible, at least not the way you want to use it. Second, you'll want to read up on explicit implementation of interface members. How they interact with the public members can be complicated and it can be a deep subject, particularly around what you tried to do. Because of the first thing, though, the question isn't really about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you should just use an ObservableCollection, there is no advantage to what you are trying.  Also ObservableCollection inplements IList already so no need to do that.

To do what you expect would be

```
public class Test<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    public new T this[int i]
    {
        get
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("yo");
            return base[i];
        }
        set { base[i] = value; }
    }
}
```

But just use an ObservableCollection

Comment: A note to OP about shadowing: Once you cast to the base class, the static type information for `Test<T>`, which includes `new T this[int i]`, is lost, so you would have to use your `t` variable to access this property; the `oc` variable would still use the base implementation.